# geodjango wrong srid when it saves feature

Tags: python, django, geodjango

I tried to read data from a shape file and save them into database. well here is my code

```
lyr = ds[0]
for feat in lyr:
    geom_t = feat.geom.transform(wgs84, clone=True)
    print(geom_t.wkt)
    print(feat.geom.wkt)

    name =''
    Twoway='1'

    data = {
        'name': name,
        'Twoway': Twoway,
        'geom': geom_t.wkb
    }
    form = Street_Form(data)
    if form.is_valid():
        savedlocation = form.save()
```

well it saves and works fine. I printed some of my geometries as wkt before saving to databse and here is the result

```
  print(geom_t.wkt): LINESTRING (50.9847540637495 35.8384680697353,50.9850968571006 35.8383655346687)

   print(feat.geom.wkt): LINESTRING (50.9847540637495 35.8384680697353,50.9850968571006 35.8383655346687)
```

As you can see they are `EPSG:4326` and nothing is wrong. 
Here is my model

```
class str(models.Model):
    geom = models.LineStringField(srid=4326)
```

but when I read data from database they are as following

```
"LINESTRING(0.000457917485762628 0.000321907544087987,0.000457920236524686 0.000321915031075541)"
```

the above result is from this query

```
select st_astext(geom) from public."app_str"
```

well the geometries are misplaced, where is the problem?why this happens?

Comment: Please check your migrations and the database itself - is it also 4326 over there? What does `ST_AsEWKT()` return?  (There is no need to `.transform()` your `feat.geom` above, but this is not the problem)

Comment: @Udi I have checked all of them the problem fixed with a trick, I generated a new geometry from geom_t.wkb and tried to save it and it worked fine. I have no idea why this happened?